# How to do pixel manipulations in C++? - Linux

Tags: c++, graphics, pixel

## My Goal:

I would like to **independently manipulate pixels color** of a *created* window like a bitmap picture.
I would prefer a **native library targeting Ubuntu -> Linux**. It may be working with a function like:

```
SetPixel(int x,int y,int Color) {

  //Some code that set the color of one pixel by his coordinates x and y

  return 0;//May return an error
}
```

It will set the color of a pixel in the window by his position

## Problems:

I already tried many tutorials *(which are using Graphics.h or Windows.h)* , but **none of them were working** on my computer, **I could be doing something wrong** but *what I found* isn't explicit. Anyway, **I wouldn't know how to download a library** without instructions. I believe that it doesn't work on Linux.

SDL2 isn't native of Linux. by the way

If any clarification is needed, please add a comment or suggest an edit

Comment: [Load the image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h), modify the pixel array, [write the image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image_write.h).

Comment: Forget *everything* about `Graphics.h`. it's an obsolete header used by an obsolete (and pre-standard) implementation (Turbo C++). Noone uses that anymore; it has been obsolete for more than 20 years.

Comment: Some libraries you may want to investigate: [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/), [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/), [ImageMagik](https://imagemagick.org/index.php), [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) - and there are lots more out there.. You may also want to investigate things like `OpenGL` and `Vulkan` and GPU *shaders*.

Comment: I'd recommend **CImg** at http://cimg.eu/

Comment: CImg is exactly that - a single cross-platform C++ header file and no libraries.

Comment: Sorry @MarkSetchell It looks like CImg isn't working correctly, each time I try an example program I get an infinite number of errors telling there is undefined references...

Comment: Much as I'd like to help, I can't advise on code I cannot see. Questions are free, and answers, so if you have some CImg code, feel free to ask a new question and tag it as such. Show also how you compile and link it and which platform you use.

Comment: Your question is basically "How do I modify values in an array." SDL, etc. are overkill and completely unnecessary for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the easy solution something similar to the code below

```
#include <X11/Xlib>
bool SetPixel(uint16_t X,uint16_t Y,uint32_t Color){
    XSetForeground(_Display,_GraphicCTX,Color);
    XDrawPoint(_Display,_Window,_GraphicCTX,X,Y);
    return true;
}

bool Setup(){ //Use it first to make every graphical manipulations working :)
    Display=XOpenDisplay(0);//Create a display
    Window=XCreateSimpleWindow(Display,DefaultRootWindow(Display),0,0,480,360,0,0,0);   //Create a Window
    XMapWindow(Display,Window);//Make the Window visible
    GraphicCTX=XCreateGC(Display,Window,0,NIL);//Create a Graphics Context
    //v Wait for a MapNotify XEvent for next commands
    XSelectInput(Display,Window,StructureNotifyMask);
    while(1){
        XEvent E;
        XNextEvent(Display,&E);
        if(E.type==MapNotify)break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I used X11 as it is the native graphical protocol of Linux.

In fact, I made a library to make everything simpler with a class.

The setup function is required to be run before any graphical operations else it won't do anything!

This can work, but for advanced development, you'll need play with images and more! There is a very great [manual for Xlib](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/)!

Answer (score 1):

You should study SDL2. It's pretty easy to learn and I recommend you to read these articles, they are a great and complety tutorial.

http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php

What you need in special is available in this one:
http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/08_geometry_rendering/index.php

Only to show you the functions:

```
SDL_RenderSetDrawColor( myRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
SDL_RenderDrawPoint( myRenderer, cordX, cordY);
```

So you are able to choose the color and change the pixels independently

PS: It's works on ubuntu, the articles will teach you how to configure everything you need.
PS2: If you need help contact me, my OS is also ubuntu.

Comment: SDL2 is a really good example, **it can do what I want**, yay! But I saw it has a lot of things that I won't need, so **I'm looking for a way to make a library to only have a SetPixelColor() function** and maybe a WindowSize() function *as well as a Setup() function if it needs to define something first*. Making a library just by reusing the code needed, **not include SDL**.

Comment: @LéololDB I think you'll struggle to find a library smaller than SDL2. SDL2 is really lightweight. Just a single dynamic library (1.1 MB) and a handful of headers (1.7 MB). Contrast that with Qt which is **hundreds of megabytes** in size. I've used both. SDL2 is pretty easy to learn and (as you said) does a little more than just setting pixels. Some of my earliest projects as a budding programmer are games made with SDL2. I followed the same tutorial linked in the answer. I strongly recommend using SDL2!

Comment: I will try to maybe find a way to take some parts of the code of SDL (if I can) so I could make a new library that would have just what I need.

Comment: @LéololDB Why not just use SDL2? Why make things difficult for yourself?

Comment: For the moment I'll make a library including SDL2 (with a #include) but when I'll have enough time I'll take parts of the code that I need.

Comment: SDL2 is the best low-level way to do what you are asking. Also, soon you gonna get bored with so simple functions and you will want to be able to do more things. Like handle with keyboard and mouse inputs (events ) and use images in your programs, and using SDL2 you will able to do that. It may be a little complex to learn and setup in the beginning, but after the firsts articles it become easier.